# Como importar bibliotecas direto da index

Tags: javascript, html

Eu andei lendo alguns tópicos sobre como o assunto, mas não encontrei nenhum que explique isso.
Oque eu gostaria de fazer é, em vez de utilizar:

```php
<script src="node_modules/php/index.js">
</script>
```

Eu queria saber se tem como puxar tudo oque precisa, por que ali em src, eu defini que eu puxaria da index de php, mas se no código ele pedir um require de alguma outra lib diferente, como posso fazer para colocar isso nele? Eu pensei em utilizar dois src, sendo

```
<script src="node_modules/php/index.js" src="node_modules/execa/index.js">
</script>
```

Mas não sei se funciona. Bem, eu fico recebendo no meu console que o php está pedindo pelo execa, mas eu não sei como adicionar ele ali logo no código, como posso fazer isso? Eu tenho o execa, mas não sei como fazer isso direto na index.

[image: .]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use o import de script mais de uma vez:

```
<script src="node_modules/php/index.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/execa/index.js"></script>
```

Utilize quantas vezes precisar, mas nunca mais de um src dentro da mesma tag.

Comment: Se eu fizer ```<script src="node_modules/php/index.js"></script>``` o conteúdo dele fecha no ```</script>``` então, ao fazer um novo script, vai ter relação com o anterior?

Comment: Vai sim. Todos os scripts indexados no HTML terão seu Javascript instanciado no topo da página.
Ou seja, todas as bibliotecas ou scripts que você inserir terão acesso uns aos outros as mesmas funções e eventos declarados no script.

Comment: Meio que ao você inserir vários scripts todos serão inseridos numa única página. Vai ser como se fosse um arquivo js grandão, compartilhando todo o conteúdo entre si.

Comment: Saquei, então para isso eu tenho que fazer o import dentro do head, e não no body?

Comment: Pode colocar onde quiser. O ideal é você colocar os imports javascript sempre no final do html, antes do fechamento da tag body, assim o conteúdo da pagina não vai precisar esperar o js carregar para ser exibido.